# The effect of multiple Alcubierre rings

Tags: space-travel, warp-drives

[image: IXS Enterprise Concept]

In all of the descriptions and visualizations I've ever seen of the Alcubierre drive but one, it takes the form of a single ring or toroid surrounding a spherical volume of flat space. The exception is the design behind the *IXS Enterprise* made by Harold White and Mark Rademaker which has *two* rings spaced along the forward axis. Given White's involvement, I'd assume this is reasonable according to at least some versions of the theory, but I'm confused about what this would do to the flat space.

I can see four possibilities: the rings don't interact at all, and they both enclose a plain sphere; they join in an organic shape, like magnetic fields; they maintain their end caps and join cylindrically (i.e. pill-shaped); or they join to a larger elliptical field stretched out along the forward axis. I probably would have discounted the pill shape entirely, but during White's talk at SpaceVision he refers to it as being "hot dog shaped".

Which of these is accurate? And say one were to add even more rings; could this, in theory, extend the length of the safe volume indefinitely?

Comment: The wikipedia article on the IXS Enterprise says the two rings are used to reduce power requirements. Let me add, for the record, that is still requires negative power and that there is no proposed mechanism yet for generating any amount of negative power

Comment: I interpreted that to mean "why enclose a full sphere around this hull when we can work with a smaller space in a different shape." It means _something_ is happening, but it doesn't say exactly what.